# Cannot execute protractor tests using headless chrome on Selenium Grid nodes

Tags: selenium, protractor, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid, google-chrome-headless

I'm using Selenium server 3.8.1, with the hub and 2 nodes. 
The hub and each node are executed on different machines.

Currently, I can launch the tests and they're working fine. But, I'm not able to make the headless mode run.

My config JSON only contains the capabilities object.

```
{
"capabilities":

[{
  "browserName": "chrome",
  "maxInstances": 3,
  "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver",
  "chromeOptions": {
        "args": [
              "--headless",
              "--disable-gpu",
              "--window-size=1920x1080"]
  }}]

}
```

I launch the selenium nodes using a .bat that contains the following command:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181\bin\java" -jar C:\jobs\selenium-node\selenium-server-standalone-3.8.1.jar -role node -hub http://172.16.0.5:5555/grid/register -port 5558 -nodeConfig config.json  -maxSession 3
```

The selenium node works fine and appears on the selenium grid UI. Also, the capabilities of the chrome driver include the --headless and other parameters:

```
....


capabilities: Capabilities {browserName: chrome, chromeOptions: {args: [--headless, --disable-gpu, --window-size=1920x1080]}, maxInstances: 3, platform: XP, se:CONFIG_UUID: cdc21610-4c47-4d23-9478-a20..., seleniumProtocol: WebDriver}


....
```

On the protractor.conf file I have these capabilities, that work when I run the tests locally.

```
  seleniumAddress:'http://172.16.0.5:5555/wd/hub', 
getPageTimeout: 120000,
allScriptsTimeout: 120000,
ignoreUncaughtExceptions: true,
chromeOnly:true,
directConnect: false,
framework: 'custom',
frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
capabilities: {
"javascriptEnabled": true,
"acceptSslCerts": true,
"browserName": "chrome",
"chromeOptions": {
    "args": [ "--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1920,1080"]
   }
},
```

But, when I launch the tests, the chrome driver isn't executed on headless mode. Works fine, but the different windows keep appearing.

Environment details:

- chromedriver version: `2.36.540470`
- chrome version: `69.0.3497.100`

Comment: What does the error logs says when _chromedriver isn't executed_ and what exactly do you mean by _different windows keep appearing_?

Comment: Chromedriver is executed properly, but not in headless mode. The windows of chrome appear as if the capabilities didn't have the --headless mode.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question/comment update you are using:

> chromedriverVersion: '2.36.540470, chrome version' => '69.0.3497.100'

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.36*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.36*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.36/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v63-65**

- You are using *chrome=69.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v2.42*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.42/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v68-70**

So there is a clear mismatch between the *ChromeDriver v2.36* and the *Chrome Browser v69.0*

### Solution

- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.14.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.42**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version between ***Chrome v68-70*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.42 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.42/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.